# Brezis' proposition 8.16: what is the weak formulation of the inhomogeneous Dirichlet condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm reading section *8.4 Some Examples of Boundary Value Problems* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*. At the beginning,

> Consider the problem
> $$
> (14) \quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -u^{\prime \prime}+u=f \quad \text { on } I=(0,1), \\
> u(0)=u(1)=0,
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> where $f$ is a given function (for example in $C(\bar{I})$ or more generally in $L^2(I)$ ). The boundary condition $u(0)=u(1)=0$ is called the (homogeneous) *Dirichlet boundary condition*.
>
> **Definition.** A *classical solution* of (14) is a function $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$ satisfying (14) in the usual sense. A *weak solution* of (14) is a function $u \in H_0^1(I)$ satisfying
> $$
> (15) \quad
> \int_I u^{\prime} v^{\prime}+\int_I u v=\int_I f v \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(I) .
> $$
>
> **Proposition 8.15.** Given any $f \in L^2(I)$ there exists a unique solution $u \in H_0^1$ to (15). Furthermore, $u$ is obtained by
> $$
> \min _{v \in H_0^1}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int_I\left[ (v^{\prime})^2+v^2\right] - \int_I f v\right\};
> $$
> this is Dirichlet's principle.

Then

> The method described above is extremely flexible and can be adapted to a multitude of problems. We indicate several examples frequently encountered. In each problem it is essential to specify precisely the function space and to find the appropriate weak formulation.
>
> **Example 1** (*inhomogeneous Dirichlet condition*). Consider the problem
> $$
> (16) \quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -u^{\prime \prime}+u=f \quad \text { on } I=(0,1), \\
> u(0)=\alpha, u(1)=\beta,
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ given and $f$ a given function.
>
> **Proposition 8.16.** Given $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in L^2(I)$ there exists a unique function $u \in H^2(I)$ satisfying (16). Furthermore, $u$ is obtained by
> $$
> \min _{\substack{v \in H^1(I) \\ v(0)=\alpha, v(1)=\beta}}\left\{\frac{1}{2} \int_I\left[ (v^{\prime})^2+v^2\right]-\int_I f v\right\} .
> $$
> If, in addition, $f \in C(\bar{I})$ then $u \in C^2(\bar{I})$.
>
> **Proof.** Fix any smooth function $u_0$ such that $u_0(0)=\alpha$ and $u_0(1)=\beta$. Introduce as new unknown $\tilde{u}=u-u_0$. Then $\tilde{u}$ satisfies
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> -\tilde{u}^{\prime \prime}+\tilde{u}=f+u_0^{\prime \prime}-u_0 \quad \text { on } I, \\
> \tilde{u}(0)=\tilde{u}(1)=0 .
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> We are reduced to the preceding problem for $\tilde{u}$.

It seems the function $u$ in **Proposition 8.16** is a weak solution. Could you elaborate on the variational formulation of (16)? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: As $u\in H^2(I)$, $u$ is a strong solution, meaning that the equation is satisfied a.e. on $I$, i.e., $-u'' +u$ and $f$ lie in the same equivalence class in $L^2(I)$.

Comment: @stange Maybe I'm wrong but we need $f \in C (\overline I)$ to have $u \in C^2 (\overline I)$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Looks like not everyone uses the same notation. In the book you're reading, the author calls a classical ($C^2$) solution also a strong solution. For me, a strong solution is a solution $u\in H^2$ which satisfies the given PDE almost everywhere.

Comment: @stange Your comment clears my confusion. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @stange Could you please have a check on my below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
K := \{v \in H^1 (I) : v(0) = \alpha \text{ and } v(1) = \beta\}.
$$

Then $K$ is a closed convex subset of $H^1 (I)$. We have $-u^{\prime \prime}+u=f$ on $I$ implies
$$
-\int_I u'' (v-u) + \int_I u(v-u) = \int_I f(v-u)
\quad \forall v \in K.
$$

By integration by parts,
$$
\int_I u'' (v-u) = u' (1) (v-u) (1) - u' (0) (v-u) (0) - \int_Iu' (v-u)'= - \int_Iu' (v-u)'.
$$

Then we have the weak formulation
$$
\int_I u' (v-u)' + \int_I u(v-u) = \int_I f(v-u)
\quad \forall v \in K.
$$

Comment: We don't want to test with function that have a different boundary condition than $u$, so testing with $v\in H^1_0(I)$ is not what we want. And regarding your conclusion, the weak formulations are $\textbf{not}$ the same, as the solution space is different.

Comment: @stange I have just edited my answer. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @stange Thank you so much for your verification!